# Once Upon A Time family tree

Tags: once-upon-a-time

The interconnectedness of heroes and villains in Once Upon A Time makes for a very intriguing storyline and dialogue.

Has anyone ever drawn up a family tree showing relationship/genealogy of characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, there's [plenty](https://www.google.com/search?q=once+upon+a+time+family+tree).  <strike>There's an [official one](http://abc.go.com/shows/once-upon-a-time/family-tree) that covers the 'core' relationships.</strike>  There's this [real thorough one](http://anderssondavid1.deviantart.com/art/Once-Upon-A-Time-Family-Tree-484941318) that includes not just family ties, but also the numerous romances (it's not updated for all of S4 though, so it's a season behind).  That one really highlights how ridiculous things are when you try to map out all the *many* connections between the huge extended cast of characters.

Here's the second one, so this isn't a links-only answer.  It's from anderssondavid1 on Deviant Art.

[image: huge family tree]

Comment: The ABC link doesn't seem to work for me... and I love that detailed one, just wish it had names.

Comment: @user1337 Yeah, link rot got it.  I can't find where it moved to on ABC's site, so it may be gone.